# When user presses the certain key, make it like he clicked the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing calculator in JavaScript and I want users be able to hit key (ex:8) and make it like he clicked the button.
Here is part of my HTML code (JavaScript is done already):

```
<div class="row">
    <button onclick="addNum(this)">7</button>
    <button onclick="addNum(this)">8</button>
    <button onclick="addNum(this)">9</button>
    <button onclick="addOp(this)">×</button>
</div>
```

Maybe you can suggest some jQuery plugin (I have little knowledge of it).
Thanks

Comment: [jQuery Calculator](http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a separate `window.onkeydown` function to handle all the key events that happens. so that you can have the full control over the input. Please have a look at the [Key code table](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/#article-header-id-1) for more key codes

```html
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (code => 96 && code <= 105) { //numbers
        addNum(this);
    } else if (code == 107) { //add
        addOp(this);
    } else if (code == 107) { //other keycodes
        // their codes
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks this helped :)